# Dynamic SQL DateTime comparison while data archive is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, database-administration

I have written this stored procedure for data purge from one of my tables. I have made it configurable to either archive the data or do a hard delete. Since the volume of data is quiet large, i am using loops to do the same.
The delete part of it is working fine However the archive part of it is giving me hard times and i am kind of stuck there with multiple tries.
Here is my SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPurgeRecords_new] (
 @Age AS INT,
 @NumberOfLoops AS BIGINT,
 @DeleteSize BIGINT,
 @IsArchive BIT
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN

DECLARE @CurrentLoop AS BIGINT;
SET @CurrentLoop = 0

declare @cutoffDate datetime;
declare @maxXDate datetime;
declare @loop varchar(50);

select @cutoffDate = dateadd(year,-@Age,getdate())
select @maxXDate = max(dateCreated)  from cbr_audit where dateCreated < @cutoffDate

declare @date varchar(100), @cmd varchar(1000),@archivedate varchar(100)

set @date = (select FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd'));
set @archivedate = (select FORMAT(@maxXDate, 'yyyyMMdd'));

declare @backupTable varchar(100)
set @backupTable =  'cbr_audit_Backup_' + @date;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION   
    WHILE @CurrentLoop < @NumberOfLoops
    BEGIN       
             IF @IsArchive = 1
                          BEGIN
                         --Archive the records into a backup table
                          IF OBJECT_ID (@backupTable, N'U') IS NULL 
                              begin
                                 set @cmd = 'SELECT * INTO [cbr_audit_Backup_'+ @date +'] FROM [cbr_audit] WITH (NOLOCK) where convert(datetime,dateCreated,101) <=  CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + @archivedate + ''', 101)'
                                 exec(@cmd)
                              end

                             --Delete the rows from cbr_audit table
                             DELETE 
                                FROM dbo.cbr_audit
                                WHERE id IN 
                                    (SELECT TOP(@DeleteSize) id
                                     FROM dbo.cbr_audit WITH (NOLOCK)
                                     WHERE dateCreated  <= @maxXDate);                      

                         END

             ELSE
                         BEGIN
                        -- Delete the records
                            DELETE 
                                FROM dbo.cbr_audit
                                WHERE id IN 
                                    (SELECT TOP(@DeleteSize) id
                                     FROM dbo.cbr_audit WITH (NOLOCK)
                                     WHERE dateCreated  <= @maxXDate);

                            END
                                  -- WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:500';        
                SET @CurrentLoop = @CurrentLoop + 1;            
                set @loop = cast(@currentloop as varchar(50))       
                RAISERROR (@loop, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 
    END
COMMIT TRANSACTION  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH     
--Rollback     
                RETURN
 END CATCH
END
```

In This SP, in the archive part of code  the dynamic sql is not giving any results. DateCreated is of Datetime type. Can someone please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using SQL 2016 or above, try CONCAT, something like:

```
select concat('SELECT * INTO [cbr_audit_Backup_', @date,'] FROM [cbr_audit] WITH (NOLOCK) where convert(datetime,dateCreated,121) <=  ''', CONVERT(varchar(30), @archivedate , 121), '''')
```

few more things: 
I strongly recommend you always to use style 121 (canonical)

- or 126 (ISO8601) so you'll SQL will not be confused by mm/dd/yyyy (101) or dd/mm/yyyy (103).
- you are deleting by chunks, but the transaction is for all the block. consider doing only transaction for each delete (implicit)
- instead insert into and then delete, have a look to OUTPUT clause to DELETE [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)